# Multiple checkbox filter with jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter

I am working with jquery input checkbox filter. While I am searching for the reference I got the following code from 'StackOverflow' that works perfectly. But my problem is how to use this code with logical and operation. ie, if I checked two checkboxes, it only displays content with both value, not either or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.post').show();

$('.menu-item').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
    var post = $('.post').hide();

    var elements = $('.menu-item').find('input:checked');

    if(elements.length){
        elements.each(function () {
            post.filter('.' + this.id).show();
        });
    }
    else
        post.show();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mzvNL/1/

Comment: can you explain what exactly you want?

Comment: "if I checked two checkboxes, it only displays content with both value, not either or" -> Are you sure of that? To me it does select boxes with any of the values of the checkes boxes (just tried your sample).

Comment: I am sorry for my English. I meant that it should only display content with both values, not either or. but now it displays any of the values of the checks boxes.  That I intended to say I need it to perform like 'logical AND' operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

**Demo**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.post').show();

  $('.menu-item').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
    var $posts = $('.post').hide();
    var $elements = $('.menu-item').find('input:checked');

    $posts
      .filter(function() {
        var $post = $(this);
        return $elements.toArray().every(function(element) {
          return $post.hasClass($(element).attr('id'));
        });
      })
      .show();
  });
});
```

```css
article {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <input id="beans-palak" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="beans-palak">Beans Palak</label>
    
    <input id="bengal-lentils" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="bengal-lentils">Bengal Lentils</label>
    
    <input id="bombay-potatoes" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="bombay-potatoes">Bombay-Potatoes</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<article class="post beans-palak">palak</article>
<article class="post bombay-potatoes">potatoes</article>
<article class="post bengal-lentils">lentils</article>
<article class="post bombay-potatoes bengal-lentils">potatoes lentils</article>
<article class="post bengal-lentils bombay-potatoes bengal-lentils">all</article>
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I need. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can I ask one more doubt, ie. If I have multiple 'li's and each li has different checkboxes. When I check two values from single li, Can it be displays any of the values in checkbox

Comment: @krishna It's certainly possible, you can make use of [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and combine it with `Array.every`.

Comment: Could you please explain it with code. As I don't know about these functions